# Converting string to date in SAS

Tags: sas

I have created this macro variables and printed it:

```
%let date = input('22Aug2020',date9.);
%put &date;
```

but when I print it, it prints:

```
input('22Aug2020',date9.)
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Doesn't look like an error to me. It did exactly what you told it to do.  Please show how you plan to use the macro variable's value in actual SAS code.

Comment: May want to google the concept of using functions when declaring macro variables. Tom's comment will then trigger the "Aha" moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that you are forgetting that macro variables are *text*, so SAS is doing precisely what you ask it to.

If you want a macro variable to contain a function *that is resolved*, you use `%sysfunc`.

```
%let date = %sysfunc(inputn(22AUG2020,date, 9));
```

[`inputn`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n1xdirhugd30qcn1szvchqcss3wv.htm) is the function that performs input and returns a numeric (as you want).  Two things you may notice:

- `%SYSFUNC` does not use quotation marks - leave them off, unless you want the text character `"` or `'` to actually appear.  It does not serve the purpose of delimiting text values.
- `INPUTN` has a few ways you can specify the information name. You could provide `date9.` in one argument, or you could split it up the way I do, both are fine.

But the better way to do this is as Reeza says - directly with the `'22AUG2020'd` directive.

Answer (score 2):

This will generally do what you need - add the trailing d, which [tells SAS to interpret the value as a date](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/lrcon/9.4/p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm#n1bbnuc86c5c5hn113qbpt5u9g5f).

```
%let date = '22AUG2020'd;
%put &date.;
```

SAS will interpret 22Aug2020 with the trailing `d` as a SAS date and process it correctly 99% of the time.

Comment: I'm curious what the 1% is that it fails!

Comment: Just the ones where the dates wouldn't work anyways, ie SQL pass through.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, makes sense.